# Is it safe to omit braces around the command name being defined with \newcommand or \renewcommand?

Tags: macros, braces, syntax, grammar, renewcommand

I see both type of coding style in use:

```tex
\newcommand{\hello}{Hello, World}
```

```tex
\newcommand\hello{Hello, World}
```

My question: Is there any situation where removing the braces around the command name being defined with `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand` would provide a result or behavior that is different from what it would if we do not remove the braces around the command?

Comment: yes  (to the question in the title) no (to the question in the post)

Comment: No difference, except if you forget the backslash or use numbers together with letters, but the code would be wrong anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do people use braces around the control sequence in \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340734/why-do-people-use-braces-around-the-control-sequence-in-newcommand) See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1914/82917

Comment: Thank you for providing the duplicate links. I found this answer the most useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1917/18587